# Object Request with JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a problem with a JSP file. I want to retrieve the header but I have an error:

```
Une erreur s'est produite à la ligne: 45 dans le fichier jsp: /logTest.jsp
Enumeration cannot be resolved to a type
42: String headerString = "";
43: String name = "";
44: 
45: for (Enumeration en = request.getHeaderNames(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
46:     name = (String)en.nextElement();
47:     headerString = headerString + name + "=<B>" + request.getHeader(name) + "</B><BR>";
48: }
```

My object (request) is not null so I don't understand why I have this error.

Can you help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please format the stack trace as code; we can't read it.

Comment: FYI: Markdown markup rules can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to explicitly import `java.util.Enumeration`. The stack trace gave you the answer: "Enumeration cannot be resolved to a type".